# Granting access to a git repository via password

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

Currently I need to publish some projects for my job application, but I don't know their usernames or proper emails. Is there a possibility to grant access to files via password or via link(like in Dropbox)to the repository and not through invitation? I am using bitbucket as a server.

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of the following:

1. Setup a deploy key for you repository (which will grant read-only access for you repo), and attach the key to your application.. I don't know if the receiver of the application would bother using the key, but it's an option.
2. Make the repository public for the time being. Then you would simply just have to attach a link to the BitBucket repository, and the source code will be able to be looked at by whomever is reading your application.
3. Host your own git repository on a server, and setup a web-front for the repository. This is however the more advanced/time consuming option, with an end result very similar to option 2. However, compared to option 2, the repository will be harder to find without the link, if you'd prefer the code to be somewhat privately accessible. You can also setup user authentication with this option, which can utilize a basic user/password method.